# how can i extract '\r' separated dictionaries of a csv file using python

Tags: python, json

I want to get values of the keys like "Physical memory KBytes total:8017608, and all other dictionaries.

For other dictionaries I am using python code like:

```
import csv
import json
x = []
    # r"""{"data":"foo \\r\\n bar"}"""
for line in open("forcasting/eventdat_Feb/event_nw_2019-02-01.json", 'r', encoding='utf8'):
    x.append(json.loads(line))
#for line in open("forcasting/eventdat_Feb/event_nw_2019-02-01.json", 'r', encoding='utf8',errors='ignore'):

#print(x[0]['_source']['text1']['log'])
f = csv.writer(open("forcasting/eventdat_Feb/Dart95/1st_feb.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["timestamp","machine","id","customer","type","entered","enteredDate","servertime","username","host","text1_log","text2_log","string1_log"])

    for key in x:
            if key["_source"].get("scrip")=="31":
                    f.writerow([
                            key["_source"].get("@timestamp"),
                            key["_source"].get("machine"),
                            key["_source"].get("id"),
                            key["_source"].get("customer"),
                            key["_source"].get("type"),
                            key["_source"].get("entered"),
                            key["_source"].get("enteredDate"),
                            key["_source"].get("servertime"),
                            key["_source"].get("username"),
                            key["_source"].get("host"),
                            key["_source"].get("text1").get("log"),
                            key["_source"].get("text2").get("log"),
                            key["_source"].get("string1").get("log")
                    ])
```

But in this one -- `key["_source"].get("text1").get("log")`, I'm trying

```
key["_source"].get("text1").get("log").get("Physical memory KBytes total")
```

but it is not working.

thank you

problem in extracting data of highlighted part of this image
[image]

this is the highlited part:

"text1":{"log":"Physical memory:\r Physical memory KBytes total: 8017608\r Physical memory KBytes in use: 5457192\r Physical memory Percentage in use: 68\r Physical memory KBytes free: 2560416\r Physical memory Percentage free: 32\r Virtual memory:\r Virtual memory KBytes total: 137438953344\r Virtual memory KBytes in use: 258064\r Virtual memory Percentage in use: 0\r Virtual memory KBytes free: 137438695280\r Virtual memory Percentage free: 100\r Swap space:\r Swap space KBytes total: 12474056\r Swap space KBytes in use: 10285812\r Swap space Percentage in use: 82\r Swap space KBytes free: 2188244\r Swap space Percentage free: 18\r mSec Sampling period: 30000\r Page reads per second: 2\r Number of processes running: 208"}

i can't share the all json files those are too large but i am attaching a sample file please check , it is our system data(elasticsearch data) in json format and i need to extract those values (values within text1) to perform some machine learning thing.

```
{"_index":"event_nw_2019-02-01","_type":"events","_id":"uB-xp2gB5-JFORtVXbZW","_score":1,"_source":{"username":"ka100982","text4":{"log":"Process Image Name: Memory Compression\r Process PID: 2628\r Process CPU: 0\r Process Elapsed: 5:22:43\r Process Mem Usage: 955508K\r  \r Process Image Name: chrome#8\r Process PID: 10312\r Process CPU: 0\r Process Elapsed: 5:21:46\r Process Mem Usage: 287852K\r Process: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\r Process Version: 71.0.3578.98\r Process Size: 1587680\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, May 24, 2018 06:37:21\r Process Last Modified Date: Tuesday, December 11, 2018 23:11:41\r  \r Process Image Name: chrome#3\r Process PID: 5556\r Process CPU: 0\r Process Elapsed: 5:21:53\r Process Mem Usage: 210620K\r Process: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\r Process Version: 71.0.3578.98\r Process Size: 1587680\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, May 24, 2018 06:37:21\r Process Last Modified Date: Tuesday, December 11, 2018 23:11:41\r  \r Process Image Name: chrome#15\r Process PID: 4516\r Process CPU: 0\r Process Elapsed: 5:20:41\r Process Mem Usage: 202464K\r Process: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\r Process Version: 71.0.3578.98\r Process Size: 1587680\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, May 24, 2018 06:37:21\r Process Last Modified Date: Tuesday, December 11, 2018 23:11:41\r  \r Process Image Name: chrome#12\r Process PID: 3428\r Process CPU: 0\r Process Elapsed: 5:21:00\r Process Mem Usage: 195764K\r Process: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\r Process Version: 71.0.3578.98\r Process Size: 1587680\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, May 24, 2018 06:37:21\r Process Last Modified Date: Tuesday, December 11, 2018 23:11:41\r  \r Process Image Name: chrome#19\r Process PID: 9628\r Process CPU: 0\r Process Elapsed: 4:25:37\r Process Mem Usage: 191124K\r Process: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\r Process Version: 71.0.3578.98\r Process Size: 1587680\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, May 24, 2018 06:37:21\r Process Last Modified Date: Tuesday, December 11, 2018 23:11:41\r  \r Process Image Name: iexplore#2\r Process PID: 9296\r Process CPU: 2\r Process Elapsed: 5:18:38\r Process Mem Usage: 173444K\r Process: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE\r Process Version: 11.00.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)\r Process Size: 822544\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, August 23, 2018 07:50:50\r Process Last Modified Date: Thursday, March 29, 2018 23:07:49\r  \r Process Image Name: chrome\r Process PID: 10152\r Process CPU: 29\r Process Elapsed: 5:21:54\r Process Mem Usage: 170452K\r Process: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\r Process Version: 71.0.3578.98\r Process Size: 1587680\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, May 24, 2018 06:37:21\r Process Last Modified Date: Tuesday, December 11, 2018 23:11:41\r  \r Process Image Name: chrome#9\r Process PID: 10228\r Process CPU: 0\r Process Elapsed: 5:21:24\r Process Mem Usage: 169132K\r Process: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\r Process Version: 71.0.3578.98\r Process Size: 1587680\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, May 24, 2018 06:37:21\r Process Last Modified Date: Tuesday, December 11, 2018 23:11:41\r  \r Process Image Name: dcuapp\r Process PID: 9864\r Process CPU: 16\r Process Elapsed: 5:21:58\r Process Mem Usage: 157184K\r Process: C:\\Program Files\\Verint\\DPA\\Client\\DCUApp.exe\r Process Version: 11,1,1,19229\r Process Size: 694272\r Process Creation Date: Thursday, July 6, 2017 14:08:28\r Process Last Modified Date: Thursday, July 6, 2017 14:08:28\r  "},"idx":12483141,"version":"","string1":{"log":"27"},"uuid":"67cf6aa9-63f8-48a5-888d-127995fc09e1","id":"0","serverDate":"2019-02-01T06:14:05Z","Tags":["AllMemoryUtilizationEvents","MemUtilizationPhysicalMemoryLessThan8GB"],"entered":"1549001637","scrip":"6","windowtitle":"","text2":{"log":"Type of run: RealTime Monitoring"},"customer":"CompuCom_Selfheal__201800016","string2":{"log":"41444"},"priority":"5","description":"Memory Statistics","enteredDate":"2019-02-01T06:13:57Z","machine":"MH-NW0-198592","text1":{"log":"Physical memory:\r Physical memory KBytes total: 8017608\r Physical memory KBytes in use: 5457192\r Physical memory Percentage in use: 68\r Physical memory KBytes free: 2560416\r Physical memory Percentage free: 32\r Virtual memory:\r Virtual memory KBytes total: 137438953344\r Virtual memory KBytes in use: 258064\r Virtual memory Percentage in use: 0\r Virtual memory KBytes free: 137438695280\r Virtual memory Percentage free: 100\r Swap space:\r Swap space KBytes total: 12474056\r Swap space KBytes in use: 10285812\r Swap space Percentage in use: 82\r Swap space KBytes free: 2188244\r Swap space Percentage free: 18\r mSec Sampling period: 30000\r Page reads per second: 2\r Number of processes running: 208"},"@timestamp":"2019-02-01T06:14:05.294Z","type":"","clientsize":"9030168","size":"0","text3":{"log":""},"path":"","executable":"","servertime":1549001645,"clientversion":"3.002.036.3038.24","host":"35.225.19.235"}}
{"_index":"event_nw_2019-02-01","_type":"events","_id":"uR-xp2gB5-JFORtVXrYC","_score":1,"_source":{"username":"gh102434","text4":{"log":""},"idx":12483142,"version":"","string1":{"log":""},"uuid":"67f31b98-21af-49a6-a6b3-0a48406329cf","id":"0","serverDate":"2019-02-01T06:14:05Z","Tags":["Clientheartbeatevent"],"entered":"1549001644","scrip":"231","windowtitle":"","text2":{"log":"Type of run: Scheduled"},"customer":"CompuCom_Selfheal__201800016","string2":{"log":""},"priority":"5","description":"Client heartbeat","enteredDate":"2019-02-01T06:14:04Z","machine":"MX-D-CIT00100","text1":{"log":"SelfHeal Client is running and responding"},"@timestamp":"2019-02-01T06:14:05.464Z","type":"","clientsize":"9030168","size":"0","text3":{"log":""},"path":"","executable":"","servertime":1549001645,"clientversion":"3.002.036.3038.24","host":"35.225.19.235"}}
```

Comment: Share your input file

Comment: What is the current behavior and the expected output? "It's not working" is not considered useful.

Comment: please add raw data in question.

Comment: You could post that highlighted part as text

Comment: @user202729 its taking all data within text1 as a string and showing Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forcasting\feb_data_extract.py", line 27, in <module>
    key["_source"].get("text1").get("log")["Number of processes running"],
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have under the "log" key is plain text, not a json object so after deserialization what you get is a string, not a dict. You will have to parse this string by yourself to retrieve the data.

The good news is that the parsing is not too complicated:

```
def parsedata(logtext):
   # 'logtext' is the whole string value for the 'log' key
   return dict(
      s.strip().split(":") 
      for s in logtext.splitlines() 
      if ":" in s and not s.endswith(":")
      )

logtext = "Physical memory:\r Physical memory KBytes total: 8017608\r Physical memory KBytes in use: 5457192\r Physical memory Percentage in use: 68\r Physical memory KBytes free: 2560416\r Physical memory Percentage free: 32\r Virtual memory:\r Virtual memory KBytes total: 137438953344\r Virtual memory KBytes in use: 258064\r Virtual memory Percentage in use: 0\r Virtual memory KBytes free: 137438695280\r Virtual memory Percentage free: 100\r Swap space:\r Swap space KBytes total: 12474056\r Swap space KBytes in use: 10285812\r Swap space Percentage in use: 82\r Swap space KBytes free: 2188244\r Swap space Percentage free: 18\r mSec Sampling period: 30000\r Page reads per second: 2\r Number of processes running: 208"

print(parsedata[logtext])
```

=>

```
{'Number of processes running': ' 208', 'Physical memory KBytes total': ' 8017608', 'Swap space KBytes in use': ' 10285812', 'Swap space Percentage free': ' 18', 'Page reads per second': ' 2', 'Physical memory Percentage free': ' 32', 'Virtual memory KBytes free': ' 137438695280', 'Physical memory Percentage in use': ' 68', 'Physical memory KBytes free': ' 2560416', 'Virtual memory Percentage in use': ' 0', 'Swap space KBytes free': ' 2188244', 'mSec Sampling period': ' 30000', 'Physical memory KBytes in use': ' 5457192', 'Virtual memory KBytes in use': ' 258064', 'Virtual memory KBytes total': ' 137438953344', 'Swap space KBytes total': ' 12474056', 'Virtual memory Percentage free': ' 100', 'Swap space Percentage in use': ' 82'}
```

EDIT:

> when i'm using it with my code to change that nested dictionary it's giving me this error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "forcasting\feb_data_extract.py", line 17, in  a = parsedata(x[i]["_source"].get("text1").get("log")) File "forcasting\feb_data_extract.py", line 11, in parsedata for s in logtext.splitlines() ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

It means that one of the lines in the log text has more than one single `":"` separator (two in this case since it yields a triplet instead of a pair).

You can change `parsedata` implemetation to get a more accurate report and eventually take appropriate action (which action is appropriate depending on what's in the line and what you want to get out of it):

```
# caveat: untested code
def parsedata(logtext):
   # 'logtext' is the whole string value for the 'log' key
   parsed = {}
   for line in logtext.splitlines:
       line = line.strip().split()
       if not line:
           # empty line
           continue 
       if ":" not in line or line.endswith(":"):
          # we ignored those lines given your initial specs
          # but you may actually want to do something with...
          # let's at least print it for inspection
          print("line is not a key:value pair: '{}' -  ignoring".format(line))
          continue
       try:
           k, v = line.split(":")
       except ValueError:
          print("line has more than one separator: '{}' -  ignoring".format(line))
          # what to do here depends on what the line looks like
          # and what you want to do with it. 
          continue
      parsed[k] = v

  return parsed
```

If it happens that the additional `':'` separator should actually be part of the effective value, you can either rebuild the value from the triplet (or whatever the size of the tuple):

```
splitted = s.split(":") 
# some eventual tests here if needed
k, v = splitted[0], ":".join(*splitted[1:])
```

or just use the `maxsplit` argument

```
k, v = s.split(":", 1)
```

Here again the "correct" action depends on the actual data and context so only you know how this should be handled.

Just note that all this is very basic text parsing / error handling stuff that you should really learn to write and debug by yourself (simple text parsing is actually a very common task in application programming).

Comment: but when i'm using it with my code to change that nested dictionary it's giving me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forcasting\feb_data_extract.py", line 17, in <module>
    a = parsedata(x[i]["_source"].get("text1").get("log"))
  File "forcasting\feb_data_extract.py", line 11, in parsedata
    for s in logtext.splitlines()
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required


Can any one tell me what is the problem, I'm using the parsing code in the same code I have written in my question.

Comment: @shraddha cf my edited answer - but those are things you should really learn to debug by yourself because you will have a lot of those issues when parsing loosely structured text.